# LCP, CLS and FCP metrics have different values in 'Core Web Vitals Assessment' and 'Performance' sections

Tags: lighthouse, pagespeed-insights, core-web-vitals, cumulative-layout-shift, largest-contentful-paint

Is there a reason why the **LCP**, **FCP** and **CLS** metrics have a different value in the **Core Web Vitals Assessment** and **Performance** sections?

In screenshot attached, we can see that the **LCP** metrics has a value of **1.6** seconds in the **Core Web Vitals Assessment** vs. a value of **6.4** seconds in the **Performance** section.

Is it normal behavior or is that a glitch from PageSpeed Insights?

[image: PageSpeed Insights]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are causes of the differece between CoreWebVitals assessment and PageSpeen Insights performance grade?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77316510/what-are-causes-of-the-differece-between-corewebvitals-assessment-and-pagespeen)

Comment: Yes it does, thank you @BarryPollard

What should we do when real-user data is good but not the simulated load data?

Comment: Well real-user data is more important IMHO. However simulated load data is showing potential areas for improvement. Maybe that test is too slow for the types of users you get (it's based on a global average), but what if you get an influx of slow users in the future? Or what if the reason it's fast for real users is because it's mostly repeat visitors (with cached assets) but you're putting off new visitors? So it may still be worth investigating and understanding, but maybe not as high a priority as if real user data showed it as slow.

Comment: Thank you again for your reply @BarryPollard, it is super useful! I was asking because I was wondering if Google Search Console was marking group of URLs as need improvements or as poor based on the real user data or the simulated load data. It seems like Google is looking at both right?

Comment: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9205520:
"The Core Web Vitals report shows how your pages perform, based on real world usage data (sometimes called field data)."
Lab data is for you to help improve the performance of your website - which should hopefully lead to improvements in your field data.